# SQL: select using two conditions on one columns

Tags: sql

I need to extract distinct elements of a column by using two conditions on another column. For example:

```
c1  |  c2  
---------
u   |  a
v   |  b
w   |  c
x   |  a
x   |  b
x   |  c
y   |  a
y   |  c
```

I want the entries of c1 when c2 does contain 'a' but not 'b'. The returned names should be 'u' and 'y'.

Any help are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Comment: I tried "SELECT DISTINCT c1 from table WHERE c2 = 'a' AND c2 != 'b'", intersect and a few other method. It didn't work...

Comment: I agree this smells of homework, but it was just intriguing enough that I offered an answer anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the conceptually easiest ways to do this would be to aggregate on the `c1` column and just assert that `a` is present and `b` is not present:

```
SELECT c1
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY c1
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN c2 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN c2 = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it never came to me that using case to map it into a different feature.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something the SQL excels at, so it's a bit clunky. This naive implementation is fairly vanilla and should work with little modification under most dialects.

In DB2 you may need to add "with ur" to the inner query to prevent locking.

```
select c1 from yourtable
where c2 = 'a'
  and c1 not in (
    select c1 from yourtable where c2 = 'b'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.c1
FROM table as t
WHERE 
t.c2 LIKE '%a%'
AND NOT t.c2 LIKE '%b%'
```